# What is the right way of copying string set (in copy constructor and assignment operator)?

Tags: c++, string, copy-constructor, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Code Block A:

```
typedef struct NAMEOFTHESTRUCT {
    long lNumber;
    std::set<wstring> szStrings;

    NAMEOFTHESTRUCT() {
        lNumber = -1L;
    };

    NAMEOFTHESTRUCT(const NAMEOFTHESTRUCT& src) {
        lNumber = src.lNumber;
        szStrings = src.szStrings; //COPY THIS WAY
    };

    NAMEOFTHESTRUCT& operator =(const NAMEOFTHESTRUCT& src) {
        lNumber = src.lNumber;
        szStrings. = src.szStrings; //COPY THIS WAY
        return *this;
    };
}
```

Code Block B:

```
typedef struct NAMEOFTHESTRUCT {
    long lNumber;
    std::set<wstring> szStrings;

    NAMEOFTHESTRUCT() {
        lNumber = -1L;
    };

    NAMEOFTHESTRUCT(const NAMEOFTHESTRUCT& src) {
        lNumber = src.lNumber;
        if (!src.szStrings.empty()) // COPY THIS WAY
            szStrings.insert(src.szStrings.begin(), src.szStrings.end());
    };

    NAMEOFTHESTRUCT& operator =(const NAMEOFTHESTRUCT& src) {
        lNumber = src.lNumber;
        if (!src.szStrings.empty()) // COPY THIS WAY
            szStrings.insert(src.szStrings.begin(), src.szStrings.end()); 
        return *this;
    };
}
```

In Code block A & B, the copying of string set is different.

Which is the right way of copying a string set? Why?

Does it differs if the copying is in copy constructor/ assignment operator? If so, why?

Comment: The use of `typedef` there is awkward and useless, all-caps identifiers are often used for macros, using that for types might surprise others, and might collide with macro definitions in headers you might be including.   Hungarian notation is also less and less common nowadays...

Comment: For the member variables you have in your class, you can just let the compiler generate the copy constructor and copy assignment operator for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should trust assignment, it is implemented in the type and knows the most effective way of doing it. Other than that, the second version's assignment operator is wrong, as it will *merge* the values in the set from the right hand side into the left hand side. Maybe you meant to `clear` it first?

Other than that, the copy constructor would often be spelled as:

```
NAMEOFTHESTRUCT(const NAMEOFTHESTRUCT& src)
   : lNumber(src. lNumber), szStrings(src. szStrings)
{}
```